# How to set variable data in JSON body for the code that generated by Postman in c#

Tags: c#, json, xmlhttprequest, postman, http-post

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://azuretitanicapp.azurewebsites.net/predict");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic PEJhc2ljIEF1dGggVXNlcm5hbWU+OjxCYXNpYyBBdXRoIFBhc3N3b3JkPg==");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "ARRAffinity=a6e48b9e9d2653435be7b61998d8624b44115214104213d6c8b8c526cc56dc70; ARRAffinitySameSite=a6e48b9e9d2653435be7b61998d8624b44115214104213d6c8b8c526cc56dc70");
var body = @"{
" + "\n" +
@"    ""Pclass"": ""2"",
" + "\n" +
@"    ""Age"": ""55""
" + "\n" +
@"}";
request.AddParameter("application/json", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

This is the code and here I want to set age=72 as a variable. For example

int variable_age= 72;

in JSON body, it should be like this

age : variable_age

Please help me, I'm having a hard time for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#url-segment

Class

```
public class BodyJson
{
  public int Pclass {get;set;}
  public int Age    {get;set;}
}
```

Method

```
    var param = new BodyJson{Pclass =1 , Age = 55};
    request.AddJsonBody(param);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Thank you man for your response but I tried it but can't get the prediction value, could you please post the whole code for above example, it will be a great help to me

Comment: Can u post ur needed json ? so i can help u better.

Comment: {   
"Pclass": 1, 
"Age": 55
}

Comment: so do u want to post this as json or text ?

Comment: Json  format. I have implemented as machine learning model , every time parameter should change give a prediction score, thank you for kind help!

Comment: you can check answer now .

Comment: Thank you so much, man! You are savior !

Comment: if it possible upvote the answer so maybe next time someone can use that :)